# Tetris in C, in 200 lines

Tags: performance, c, linux, curses, tetris

I aimed at making fully functional (real) Tetris, in the shortest way possible in C. The result is a terminal game for Linux, that uses ncurses. I made it for my friend, who wanted to play it on his Arduino with LED matrix. Before doing it, I browsed for the shortest Tetris code so far. I found the [140-bytes (buggy) JS "Tetris"](https://gist.github.com/aemkei/1672254) and [36 lines of JS Tetris](http://jsfiddle.net/ova777/kFxja/) with additional HTML.

The main idea is to make it even shorter is using bitwise operations: shifting and logical OR. That was my first idea, but when I got to rotation, I had to switch to the array structure.

However, there is a problem: it is insanely CPU-intensive. My bet is the main loop that gets cycled too many times. So how can I regulate this problem? And do you think this can be done even shorter in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

#define ROWS 20
#define COLS 11
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

char Table[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
int score = 0;
char GameOn = TRUE;
double timer = 500000; //half second

typedef struct {
    char **array;
    int width, row, col;
} Shape;
Shape current;

const Shape ShapesArray[7]= {
    {(char *[]){(char []){0,1,1},(char []){1,1,0}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //S_shape     
    {(char *[]){(char []){1,1,0},(char []){0,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //Z_shape     
    {(char *[]){(char []){0,1,0},(char []){1,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //T_shape     
    {(char *[]){(char []){0,0,1},(char []){1,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //L_shape     
    {(char *[]){(char []){1,0,0},(char []){1,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //ML_shape    
    {(char *[]){(char []){1,1},(char []){1,1}}, 2},                                                   //SQ_shape
    {(char *[]){(char []){0,0,0,0}, (char []){1,1,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0,0}, (char []){0,0,0,0}}, 4} //R_shape
};

Shape CopyShape(Shape shape){
    Shape new_shape = shape;
    char **copyshape = shape.array;
    new_shape.array = (char**)malloc(new_shape.width*sizeof(char*));
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < new_shape.width; i++){
        new_shape.array[i] = (char*)malloc(new_shape.width*sizeof(char));
        for(j=0; j < new_shape.width; j++) {
            new_shape.array[i][j] = copyshape[i][j];
        }
    }
    return new_shape;
}

void DeleteShape(Shape shape){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < shape.width; i++){
        free(shape.array[i]);
    }
    free(shape.array);
}

int CheckPosition(Shape shape){ //Check the position of the copied shape
    char **array = shape.array;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < shape.width;i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < shape.width ;j++){
            if((shape.col+j < 0 || shape.col+j >= COLS || shape.row+i >= ROWS)){ //Out of borders
                if(array[i][j]) //but is it just a phantom?
                    return FALSE;
            }
            else if(Table[shape.row+i][shape.col+j] && array[i][j])
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void GetNewShape(){ //returns random shape
    Shape new_shape = CopyShape(ShapesArray[rand()%7]);

    new_shape.col = rand()%(COLS-new_shape.width+1);
    new_shape.row = 0;
    DeleteShape(current);
    current = new_shape;
    if(!CheckPosition(current)){
        GameOn = FALSE;
    }
}

void RotateShape(Shape shape){ //rotates clockwise
    Shape temp = CopyShape(shape);
    int i, j, k, width;
    width = shape.width;
    for(i = 0; i < width ; i++){
        for(j = 0, k = width-1; j < width ; j++, k--){
                shape.array[i][j] = temp.array[k][i];
        }
    }
    DeleteShape(temp);
}

void WriteToTable(){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < current.width ;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < current.width ; j++){
            if(current.array[i][j])
                Table[current.row+i][current.col+j] = current.array[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void Halleluyah_Baby(){ //checks lines
    int i, j, sum, count=0;
    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        sum = 0;
        for(j=0;j< COLS;j++) {
            sum+=Table[i][j];
        }
        if(sum==COLS){
            count++;
            int l, k;
            for(k = i;k >=1;k--)
                for(l=0;l<COLS;l++)
                    Table[k][l]=Table[k-1][l];
            for(l=0;l<COLS;l++)
                Table[k][l]=0;
        }
    }
    timer-=1000; score += 100*count;
}

void PrintTable(){
    char Buffer[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < current.width ;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < current.width ; j++){
            if(current.array[i][j])
                Buffer[current.row+i][current.col+j] = current.array[i][j];
        }
    }
    clear();
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS ;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COLS ; j++){
            printw("%c ", (Table[i][j] + Buffer[i][j])? 'O': '.');
        }
        printw("\n");
    }
    printw("\nScore: %d\n", score);
}

void ManipulateCurrent(int action){
    Shape temp = CopyShape(current);
    switch(action){
        case 's':
            temp.row++;  //move down
            if(CheckPosition(temp))
                current.row++;
            else {
                WriteToTable();
                Halleluyah_Baby(); //check full lines, after putting it down
                GetNewShape();
            }
            break;
        case 'd':
            temp.col++;  //move right
            if(CheckPosition(temp))
                current.col++;
            break;
        case 'a':
            temp.col--;  //move left
            if(CheckPosition(temp))
                current.col--;
            break;
        case 'w':
            RotateShape(temp);  //yes
            if(CheckPosition(temp))
                RotateShape(current);
            break;
    }
    DeleteShape(temp);
    PrintTable();
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    score = 0;
    int c;
    initscr();
    struct timeval before, after;
    gettimeofday(&before, NULL);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    GetNewShape();
    PrintTable();
    while(GameOn){
        if ((c = getch()) != ERR) {
          ManipulateCurrent(c);
        }
        gettimeofday(&after, NULL);
        if (((double)after.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)after.tv_usec)-((double)before.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)before.tv_usec) > timer){ //time difference in microsec accuracy
            before = after;
            ManipulateCurrent('s');
        }
    }
    printw("\nGame over\n");
    DeleteShape(current);
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
tetris: tetris.c
   gcc tetris.c -lncurses -o tetris
```

**UPDATE**

This is how I finished this little "project":

https://github.com/najibghadri/Tetris200lines

You can make any shape and play on any sized table :)

Comment: Good, performant code is not necessarily short, and may be longer than slow code.

Comment: True. Maybe I should simply set the loop to a certain frequency.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: If you've come to new insights regarding your own code and would like to share them with the rest of the people, post it as an answer - don't edit your question. If you want to get your changes reviewed, post a new question.

Comment: [codereview.se] isn't really place for short-just-to-be-short code. You might like [codegolf.se], where people get thousands of upvotes for that sort of thing.

Comment: Congratulations because your code appeared in the new [Tetris film just released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris_(film)) At approximately 21:15 into the film! I paused the screen because I wanted to see the C code and it's *exactly the same* as the start of your code posted.

Comment: @JonathanReich dammnnn  You made my day man love you

Comment: I hope the film complied with the terms of CC-BY-SA licence!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Minimize math operations

> ```
>         if (((double)after.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)after.tv_usec)-((double)before.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)before.tv_usec) > timer){ //time difference in microsec accuracy
> ```

You do four conversions from integer types to a double precision floating point type.  And do two multiplications times a million.

Consider

```
        //time difference in microsec accuracy
        if (((double)(after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec)*1000000 + (double)(after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec)) > timer) {
```

This only does two conversions and one multiplication.

Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5833240) suggests that you could instead use `uint64_t`.

```
        //time difference in microsec accuracy
        if (((after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec)*(uint64_t)1000000 + (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec)) > timer) {
```

#### Optimize the common path

Also, if this is usually false, consider flipping things around.

> ```
>         if (((double)after.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)after.tv_usec)-((double)before.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)before.tv_usec) > timer){ //time difference in microsec accuracy
>             before = after;
>             ManipulateCurrent('s');
>         }
> ```

could become

```
        if (IS_LATER(after, before)) {
            before = ADD_TO_TIMEVALUE(after, 500000);
            ManipulateCurrent('s');
        }
```

with

```
#define IS_LATER(a, b) ((a.tv_sec == b.tv_sec && a.tv_usec > b.tv_usec) || a.tv_sec > b.tv_sec)
```

and

```
#define ADD_TO_TIMEVALUE(tv, t) do {\
    tv.tv_usec += t; \
    while (tv.tv_usec >= 1000000) { \
        tv.tv_usec -= 1000000; \
        tv.tv_sec++; \
    } \
} while (0)
```

This makes updating `before` more expensive, but makes comparing `before` and `after` cheaper (up to three comparisons rather than two conversions, a multiplication, an addition, subtractions, and a comparison).  If you usually don't update, this is better.

Also note that it is more modern (C99 and later) to do this with inline functions than macros.

#### But is that the problem?

This will make the loop operate faster, but that's not really the problem.  You keep looping until a certain amount of time has passed.  Looping faster won't change that.  You might better find a way to loop more slowly to use less CPU.

You are using

> ```
>     nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
> ```

Consider instead

```
    halfdelay(1);
```

Then it should block on input until it times out (after a tenth of a second).  So if the user isn't hitting keys, this will only process five times (at most) before advancing the row.

Note:  I haven't tried it.

Comment: Didn't do exactly what you suggested, but you got the point.
Conversions were dumb, honestly I copied that part. I reduced it to one conversion with converting the time_t  (tv_sec) to suseconds_t and made timer's type of that:
if (((suseconds_t)(after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec)*1000000 + (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec)) > timer)
Also made this inline. 

Then I did the same delay with getch, but rather with timeout(1) which delays only one millisecond, and still gives the same result. Now cpu usage is 1% rather than 99%, however due to the blocking delay shape jumps got a bit weirdo. Thanks!

Comment: weirdo = the frequency changes a bit, so there are faster-slower jumps

Comment: `IS_LATER(a, b) ((a).tv_sec > (b).tv_sec || ((a).tv_sec == (b).tv_sec && (a).tv_usec > (b).tv_usec))`

Answer (score 2):

I reduced it to one conversion with converting the `time_t (tv_sec)` to `suseconds_t` and made timer's type of that:

> ```
> if (((suseconds_t)(after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec)*1000000 + (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec)) > timer)
> ```

I also made this inline. Then I did the same delay with `getch`, but rather with `timeout(1)` which delays only one millisecond, and still gives the same result. Now CPU usage is 1% rather than 99%.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

#define ROWS 20
#define COLS 11
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

char Table[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
int score = 0;
char GameOn = TRUE;
suseconds_t timer = 500000; //half second

typedef struct {
    char **array;
    int width, row, col;
} Shape;
Shape current;

const Shape ShapesArray[7]= {
    {(char *[]){(char []){0,1,1},(char []){1,1,0}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //S_shape     
    {(char *[]){(char []){1,1,0},(char []){0,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //Z_shape     
    {(char *[]){(char []){0,1,0},(char []){1,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //T_shape     
    {(char *[]){(char []){0,0,1},(char []){1,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //L_shape     
    {(char *[]){(char []){1,0,0},(char []){1,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0}}, 3},                           //ML_shape    
    {(char *[]){(char []){1,1},(char []){1,1}}, 2},                                                   //SQ_shape
    {(char *[]){(char []){0,0,0,0}, (char []){1,1,1,1}, (char []){0,0,0,0}, (char []){0,0,0,0}}, 4} //R_shape
};

Shape CopyShape(Shape shape){
    Shape new_shape = shape;
    char **copyshape = shape.array;
    new_shape.array = (char**)malloc(new_shape.width*sizeof(char*));
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < new_shape.width; i++){
        new_shape.array[i] = (char*)malloc(new_shape.width*sizeof(char));
        for(j=0; j < new_shape.width; j++) {
            new_shape.array[i][j] = copyshape[i][j];
        }
    }
    return new_shape;
}

void DeleteShape(Shape shape){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < shape.width; i++){
        free(shape.array[i]);
    }
    free(shape.array);
}

int CheckPosition(Shape shape){ //Check the position of the copied shape
    char **array = shape.array;
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < shape.width;i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < shape.width ;j++){
            if((shape.col+j < 0 || shape.col+j >= COLS || shape.row+i >= ROWS)){ //Out of borders
                if(array[i][j]) //but is it just a phantom?
                    return FALSE;
            }
            else if(Table[shape.row+i][shape.col+j] && array[i][j])
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void GetNewShape(){ //returns random shape
    Shape new_shape = CopyShape(ShapesArray[rand()%7]);

    new_shape.col = rand()%(COLS-new_shape.width+1);
    new_shape.row = 0;
    DeleteShape(current);
    current = new_shape;
    if(!CheckPosition(current)){
        GameOn = FALSE;
    }
}

void RotateShape(Shape shape){ //rotates clockwise
    Shape temp = CopyShape(shape);
    int i, j, k, width;
    width = shape.width;
    for(i = 0; i < width ; i++){
        for(j = 0, k = width-1; j < width ; j++, k--){
                shape.array[i][j] = temp.array[k][i];
        }
    }
    DeleteShape(temp);
}

void WriteToTable(){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < current.width ;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < current.width ; j++){
            if(current.array[i][j])
                Table[current.row+i][current.col+j] = current.array[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void Halleluyah_Baby(){
    int i, j, sum, count=0;
    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        sum = 0;
        for(j=0;j< COLS;j++) {
            sum+=Table[i][j];
        }
        if(sum==COLS){
            count++;
            int l, k;
            for(k = i;k >=1;k--)
                for(l=0;l<COLS;l++)
                    Table[k][l]=Table[k-1][l];
            for(l=0;l<COLS;l++)
                Table[k][l]=0;
        }
    }
    timer-=1000; score += 100*count;
}

void PrintTable(){
    char Buffer[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < current.width ;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < current.width ; j++){
            if(current.array[i][j])
                Buffer[current.row+i][current.col+j] = current.array[i][j];
        }
    }
    clear();
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS ;i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COLS ; j++){
            printw("%c ", (Table[i][j] + Buffer[i][j])? 'O': '.');
        }
        printw("\n");
    }
    printw("\nScore: %d\n", score);
}

void ManipulateCurrent(int action){
    Shape temp = CopyShape(current);
    switch(action){
        case 's':
            temp.row++;  //move down
            if(CheckPosition(temp))
                current.row++;
            else {
                WriteToTable();
                Halleluyah_Baby(); //check full lines, after putting it down
                GetNewShape();
            }
            break;
        case 'd':
            temp.col++;  //move right
            if(CheckPosition(temp))
                current.col++;
            break;
        case 'a':
            temp.col--;  //move left
            if(CheckPosition(temp))
                current.col--;
            break;
        case 'w':
            RotateShape(temp);  //yes
            if(CheckPosition(temp))
                RotateShape(current);
            break;
    }
    DeleteShape(temp);
    PrintTable();
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    score = 0;
    int c;
    initscr();
    struct timeval before, after;
    gettimeofday(&before, NULL);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    struct timespec ts = {0, 1000000}; //sleep for 0.1 millisec = 100 microsec
    timeout(1);
    inline int is_later(){
        return ((suseconds_t)(after.tv_sec*1000000 + after.tv_usec) -((suseconds_t)before.tv_sec*1000000 + before.tv_usec)) > timer;
    }
    GetNewShape();
    PrintTable();
    while(GameOn){
        if ((c = getch()) != ERR) {
          ManipulateCurrent(c);
        }
        gettimeofday(&after, NULL);
         if (is_later()) { //time difference in microsec accuracy
            ManipulateCurrent('s');
            gettimeofday(&before, NULL); //again, it's for accuracy
        }
    }
    printw("\nGame over!\n");
    DeleteShape(current);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel a bit uncomfortable seeing `struct`s passed around.
While I'd suggest not to use dynamic allocation for `Shape`s, I'd use one allocation rather than 1 + size(width) -
it would be possible to use a variable size array of pointers into a common `char[]` of variable size (declared at the end of `Shape`). But little is to be gained: even assuming 4 byte pointers, the only shape needing less than (1+3)*4 bytes for pointers is the square - but the four characters bump up the total to 16 bytes.
Just declare a 4by4 array, part of it unused:

```
#define SIZE_MAX 4
typedef struct {
    char pattern[SIZE_MAX][SIZE_MAX];
    int size, row, col;
} Shape;
Shape current;

const Shape Stencils[] = {
        {{0,1,1},
         {1,1,0},
         {0,0,0},}, 3},                 // S_shape
        …
        {{1,1},
         {1,1}}, 2},                    // SQ_shape
        {{1,1,1,1}/*, {}, {}, {}*/}, 4} // I_shape
    };

Shape clone_shape(Shape const shape) {
    Shape new_shape = shape;
    return new_shape;
}
```

`clone_shape()` (`CopyShape()` looks so C#) gets to be trivial (not sure about dispensable); `DeleteShape()` is obsolete.
In `CheckPosition()`, both `return FALSE;` are controlled by `array[i][j]`:

```
        if (array[i][j] &&                          // no phantom
            (shape.col+j < 0 || COLS <= shape.col+j
             || shape.row+i >= ROWS                 // Out of borders
             || Table[shape.row+i][shape.col+j]))   // occupied
                return FALSE;
```

Naming "the size member" of `Shape` `width` makes the control of the first nested loop in PrintTable() look odd.
Rather than initialising `Buffer` to `{0}`, I'd `memcpy()` `Table` and not need to *or/add* table entries in the loop iterated more often. I'd try out "setting current in `buffer`" unconditionally:

```
void print_table() {
    char buffer[ROWS][COLS];
    memcpy(buffer, Table, sizeof buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < current.size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < current.size; j++)
         // if(current.pattern[i][j])
                buffer[current.row+i][current.col+j] = current.pattern[i][j];

    clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS ; j++)
            printw("%c ", buffer[i][j] ? 'O': '.');
        printw("\n");
    }

    printw("\nScore: %d\n", score);
}
```